# Silex routing fails on UTF-8 uri under apache

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, silex

I have a strange behaviour with silex routing under apache2. In `index.php` I have:

```
$app->get('/★/{id}', function (Silex\Application $app, Request $req, $id) {
    return Response::create(/*...*/);
}); 
$app->get('/{id}', function (Silex\Application $app, Request $req, $id) {
    return $app->redirect("/★/{$id}");
})->assert('id', '\d+');
```

This code works pretty fine under test environment (like `php -S`,) but under apache I get 404:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /â˜…/1 was not found on this server.
```

The apache `mod_rewrite` settings are set as specified in [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Unicode routes were added in Symfony in 2.1, if I am not mistaken. Do you know what version of Symfony is being used?

Comment: `2.5.4`, but it is definitely not the reason, since everything works fine under local `php -S localhost` (`grunt php`.)

Comment: Does `->get('/%E2%98%85/{id}', ...)` work? As I understand it the browser will encode utf-8 characters before sending it, but it will display it as normal.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen No, it does not.